# Why use turbofan engines for high altitude flight?

Tags: jet-engine, turbofan, altitude, turboprop

I noticed that a lot of high altitude aircraft have turbofans for engines. So I researched and figured out that turboprop engines are more efficient. But most high altitude aircraft like the Global Hawk and U-2 have turbofan engines, with some exceptions like crazy long-endurance solar-powered aircrafts.

Is this because the low density is a problem for turboprops? or why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do jet engines get better fuel efficiency at high altitudes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/why-do-jet-engines-get-better-fuel-efficiency-at-high-altitudes)

Comment: Speed is part of the reason, see here: [Which engine is more efficient between turboprop vs jet?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1814/14897) So you may want to clarify the question by stating the turboprop planes you've come across, that is if the linked post(s) doesn't answer your question.